# does gitlab setup a symbolic link for root

Tags: git, gitlab

The gitlab instructions say to do this.

git remote add origin git@git2.home:root/rippzy.git

However, that path isn't setup on the server. There is no root dir or symbolic link.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab adds a command callout to your server's authorized keys file so when you hit it with git on ssh the gitlab-shell program takes over. Somewhere on your server there will be a repositories directory. (If you use the omnibus it is likely in /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories)

gitlab-shell calls out to normal git-receive-pack/upload-pack, but passes it the full path to that repo to work in. (In your case, /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root/rippzy.git